# Getting recent stations

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I made a database for my Android app using SQLite and it works fine. However, as I understood, SQLite calls shouldn't be made on UI thread.

Is the below okay or not?

```
/**
     * @param howMany Amount of Stations returned, passing null returns all.
     *                Sorted after last time searched.
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<Station> getRecentStations(final int howMany) {
        final ArrayList<Station> stations = new ArrayList<Station>(howMany);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor>() {

            @Override
            protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

                Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME_RECENT, COLUMNS_RECENT, null, null, null, null, COLUMN_TIME_SEARCHED + " DESC", Integer.toString(howMany));

            if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                }
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                    Station s = new Station();
                    s.setStationId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    s.setStationName(cursor.getString(1));
                    s.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)));
                    s.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)));
                    s.setType(cursor.getString(4));
                    s.setTimeSearched(cursor.getString(5));
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                    stations.add(s);


                }

                db.close();
            }


        }.execute();
        return stations;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However as I understood SQLite calls shouldn't be made on UI thread.

To be honest I wasn't aware of this: I make SQLite calls on the UI thread in many apps.
I think it's fine, unless you expect the calls might be slow.
But since you already got it working with `AsyncTask`,
then you can just as well leave as it is.

I have some other recommendations though.

Change the method to return `List<Station>` instead of `ArrayList<Station>`. You should try to use interface types (`List<>`) whenever possible instead of implementations (`ArrayList<>`).

A simpler way to iterate over the cursor:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Station s = new Station();
    s.setStationId(cursor.getInt(0));
    s.setStationName(cursor.getString(1));
    s.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)));
    s.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)));
    s.setType(cursor.getString(4));
    s.setTimeSearched(cursor.getString(5));
    stations.add(s);
}
```

But actually... Why does `doInBackground` return a `Cursor`? Why not do everything in this method and do nothing in `onPostExecute`? It seems that would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I returned the Cursor was because I saw a "high rated" post on SO do it, and thought perhaps it was "Good practice". Might as well do remove asyncTasks, because as you say, it shouldn't matter that they run on UI thread as long as they are quick. Will be a little simpler code.

Comment: If it's already working, I'd keep it and see how it goes.

Comment: @Jakkra I'd keep it too. Iterating the `Cursor` may in theory cost some time, so there may be cases when it should not be done on UI thread. Anyway, doing everything in a single method is more flexible, as you can decide to encapsulate the method in an `AsyncTask` and then easily change your mind.

Comment: @maaartinus Yes, I could encapsulate all in one asyncTask, however I would have to rewrite all database calls to String queries, right because I wouldn't be able to use e.g db.insert(...,...,...,..) right?

Comment: @Jakkra I don't understand. I can't see any `db.insert` in your code. I just restated janos' proposal not to split the work between `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` and do it all in the former instead. You can use `Cursor` and whatever, you can split it into multiple methods, but there'll be one method doing the whole work, which you can call from `AsyncTask.doInBackground` or directly. AFAIK the point of `onPostExecute` is to do the part of work which needs to be done on the UI thread and there's nothing like this in your code.

Comment: @maaartinus I edited the code, now everything is done inside doInBackgrond. This is only one of about 10 methods I have to modify my database. In others I use insert and other methods. I need to use asyncTask in all of those methods. I can't only have one method that executes a call from the other methods eg. add/delete/addAll methods I have. So I need to do a specific AsyncTask in every method. Hard to explain.